# How to change icon color in twitter bootstrap to dark?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

The problem is that when my menu tab item is active (like the first one here) - the icon becomes white automatically and it not visible. How to change the color of icon to black? There is class to make it white `icon-white`, but there is no class to make it dark.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="icon-fire"></i> Newest</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="icon-star"></i> Most popular</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="icon-heart"></i> Etc.</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try overriding the `.active` styling by adding this to your icons: `background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png") !important;` (you might have to adjust the path, but probably not).

There are only two available colors; the default dark gray one, and the white one. You can't change the color to other than those two, because they're being grabbed from a static sprited `png`.

To have more control on the size of such *icons* and their color, take a look at [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/), built to be integrated with [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). It gives you full control, since the icons are saved in vector format as a font.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought there is way to change color, but if not... Anyway, I've checked Font Awesome a few days ago but did not really like their icons, so decided not to use them (maybe, future versions of Bootstrap will add some flexibility or more colors :) - who knows?). But is there any way to change in this very example icons to black, not white? (they become white because of `<li class="active">`)

Comment: Yeap, thanks :) Really works, but I had a little bit modify the path to image.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a method to change the color :

just go to the  **bootstrap.min.css**

and search for  **.bs-glyphicons li:hover**

and change the '**color: #fff**' to '**color : #000**' (or whatever color you want)

I tested it for one my projects and it is working perfectly. Hope this helps you as well.